# Angular reactive form setting values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a list of items.
I can add to this list and also edit this(Problem here)
When I click to the element there is dialog box with reactive form.
Adding working correct, but when I try to edit multiple choice items are empty.
Here code when adding :

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    lastName: this.fb.control(''),
    firstName: this.fb.control(''),
    secondName: this.fb.control(''),
    fio: this.fb.control(''),
    iin: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(\d{12})$/)]),
    email: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.email,]),
    status: this.fb.control(''),
    systems: this.fb.control(''),
    roles: this.fb.control(''),
    organization: this.fb.control(''),
    userName: this.fb.control(''),
    newPassword: this.fb.control(''),
    newPassword2: this.fb.control(''),
  })
```

Here when editing (user is object where contains all user details) :

```
this.form = this.fb.group({

    lastName: user.fio[0],
    firstName: this.fb.control(user.fio[1]),
    secondName: this.fb.control(user.fio[2]),
    iin: this.fb.control(user.iin, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(\d{12})$/)]),
    email: this.fb.control(user.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email,]),
    status: this.fb.control(user.status),
    systems: this.fb.control(user.systems),
    roles: this.fb.control(user.roles),
    organization: this.fb.control(user.organization),
    userName: this.fb.control(user.userName),
    newPassword: this.fb.control(user.newPassword),
    newPassword2: this.fb.control(user.newPassword2),
    id: this.fb.control(user.id),

  })
```

When I open form lastname firstname fio shows but multiple choice items are not showing.

**Notice** : When I console log fb.conrols('roles') for example. It has values I set.

[image]

Here's my html template :

```
<mat-form-field class="role__input">
    <mat-label>{{ 'Роль' | translate }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select #mySelect formControlName="roles" required multiple>
      <mat-label class="role_label">{{ 'ЕНСИ' | translate }}</mat-label>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles.roleEnsi" [value]="role">
        {{role.nameRu}}
      </mat-option>
      <mat-label class="role_label">{{ 'ФОРМИРОВАНИЕ  СРЕЗОВ' | translate }}</mat-label>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles.roleFs" [value]="role">
        {{role.nameRu}}
      </mat-option>
      <mat-label class="role_label">{{ 'АДМИНИСТРАТОР' | translate }}</mat-label>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles.roleAdmin" [value]="role">
        {{role.nameRu}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What do you mean by multiple choice not showing ?

Comment: multiple choice selects are empty, even if I set them

Comment: Please provide the `.html`, because your problem obviously hasn't something to do with your ts file

Comment: I added html template

Comment: In `mat-option`: What definition has `roles.roleFs`? Is it the same as `user.roles`?

Comment: I think I figured out what's wrong :))) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all answers, I solved this question today.
Problem was about objects. I set object to [value] so after retrieving data from database objects were not equal .
Two different objects (even if they both have zero or the same exact properties) will never compare equally. If you need to compare the equality of two object's properties. 
Sooo I changed structure to accept id and transform id to object when sending to backend. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **patchValue**

```
this.form.patchValue(user);
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-wxj3hg?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: `roles: [user.roles]` is an array, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Change your formControl `roles` to `roles: this.fb.control([])`, because I has an array as data.

You can set the data by:

```
this.form.setValue(object);
```

If you use a `mat-select`, then you can put the multiple options like so:

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Roles</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="roles">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let role of user.roles" [value]="role">
        {{ role }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: No adding new user works perfectly, editing also. But when I edit it doesn't show values of user in multiple selects

Comment: I miss the context. What do you mean with edit it? And what do you mean with multiple selects?

Comment: I click to my list, form appears again. And this form must be filled with selected user data to edit.

Comment: It doesn't show, because your formField is a string type, not array.

Comment: How does your `.html` look like?

Comment: When I build fb.group {} I provide an array.

Comment: Change your `roles: this.fb.control("")` to `roles: this.fb.control([])`

Comment: Yes, I changed that. But it didn't help

Comment: Then there is no mistake in the ts.file. Your template is faulty probably

Answer (score 0):

Set the new values through the form control

```
roles: this.fb.control(user.roles);

this.form = this.fb.group({

    lastName: [user.fio[0]],
    firstName: this.fb.control(user.fio[1]),
    secondName: this.fb.control(user.fio[2]),
    iin: this.fb.control(user.iin, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(\d{12})$/)]),
    email: this.fb.control(user.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email,]),
    status: this.fb.control(user.status),
    systems: this.fb.control(user.systems),
    roles: this.fb.control(user.roles),
    organization: this.fb.control(user.organization),
    userName: this.fb.control(user.userName),
    newPassword: this.fb.control(user.newPassword),
    newPassword2: this.fb.control(user.newPassword2),
    id: this.fb.control(user.id),

  })
```

Comment: I've been doing this all the time, but selects are empty

Comment: Can you add the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
this.form.patchValue({
    lastName: user.fio[0],
    firstName: user.fio[1],
    secondName: user.fio[2],
    iin: user.iin
    email: user.email,
    status: user.status,
    systems: user.systems,
    roles: user.roles,
    organization: user.organization,
    userName: user.userName,
    newPassword: user.newPassword,
    newPassword2: user.newPassword2,
    id: user.id
  });
```

OR if user json and form model structure is same the simply try like this

```
this.form.patchValue(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :
consider userRoles is your array list of roles with ids.

in .ts

```
this.form.patchValue({
  roles:user.role_id
});
```

in .html

```
<select formControlName="roles" class="form-control">
        <option [ngValue]="role.role_id" *ngFor="let role of userRoles"> {{role.role_name}}</option>
</select>
```